# Create tables in a specific schema using psql?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql

I have a batch that allows me to create a database psql and create tables later.

```
psql -f "%cd%\db.sql" postgres
echo database creted !
pause
psql -f "%cd%\db_table.sql" mabase postgres
echo   tables creted !
```

the db.sql file:

```
CREATE DATABASE mabase;
```

and here is the db_table.sql file:

```
create table myTable(
   idTable               INT4                 not null,
   nom                  VARCHAR(254)         null,
   date           DATE                 null,
   constraint PK_idTable primary key (idTable)
);
```

This batch runs as a charme and creates the database as well as the table.

My problem is that the table is created in the public default schema. What I would like to do is create a schema first, that I can do it with one more line in my batch:

```
psql -f "%cd%\schema.sql" mabase postgres
```

schema.sql file:

```
CREATE SCHEMA mabase_schema;
```

Now the problem is to create the table in the new schema and not in the public schema.

I tried with the line:

```
psql -f "%cd%\db_table.sql" mabase_schema.mabase postgres
```

But without success !

How will I be able to define the schema in my batch file?

Comment: Prefix the table with the schema: `create table mbase_schema.mytable (...)`

Comment: tks for the suggestion. In real the file contains many tables and I have a lot of schema !this method will not be very practical in this case.

Comment: The change the search_path: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH